# why I can't store new column in laravel notification table?

Tags: php, database, laravel, notifications, backend

any way every thing is save in data column

```
 <?php

namespace App\Notifications;
class SendNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;
    public $message;
    public $model_instance;
    private $log;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @param $message
     * @param array $log
     * @param Model $model_instance
     */
    public function __construct($message, array $log = [],Model $model_instance = null )
    {

        $this->message = $message;
        $this->log = $log;
        $this->model_instance = $model_instance->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [MicroserviceChannel::class, 'database'];
    }


    public function toMicroservice($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->message;
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return $this->log;
    }




    public function toArray() {
        return [
            'group_id' => $this->model_instance
        ];
    }
}
```

this is all of my notification class
but I add new column as group_id to this table
now nothing isn't store in data column

detailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetailsdetails

because it need more details :)

Comment: Are you sure `$this->log` is an Array

Answer (score 0):

make sure add group_id in fillable in your model

Comment: i'm using guard ->    protected $guarded = ['id'];

Comment: key/value pairs add in the array return by the `toArray` method doesn't have anything to do with model `$fillable`. Notification classes will add all that key are in the return array in the data column of the `notifications` table

Answer (score 0):

`toArray` and `toDatabase` methods of notification classes must return a plain Array as explain here [Formatting Database Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#todatabase-vs-toarray).

Just ensure `toDatabase` return a plain Array like `toArray`.

I can presume `$this->id` is the `ID` of the Model instance which the Notification is related to. So you must pass that model when you instanciate the `notification` class like this

```
$user->notify(new NotificationClass($model_instance));
```

Here I use `$user->notify` you can use any Model of classes which `use Notifiable`.

And in the `NotificationClass` you'll receive the `$model_instance` in the `Constructor` like this

```
class  NotificationClass extends Notification {

    public $model_instance;

    public function __construct(Model $model_instance){
        $this->model_instance = $model_instance;
    }
    
    public function toArray() {
            return [
                'group_id' => $this->model_instance->group_id;
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: ok ,could you please give an example how to store data in that column?

Comment: I'm using $user->notify but this id is for another model

Comment: so pass that model as parameter to Notifiacation class like this `$user->notify(new NotificationClass($model_instance));` and follow the instruction which I provide above

Comment: now it's not even storing in data column:)

Comment: add in the question the code of you Notification class

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass the `$group_id` value when you call your notification like

```
$group_id=1;  

$user->notify(new ActionsNotification($group_id));
```

and then in your created notification

```
protected $group_id;

public function __construct($group_id)
    {
        $this->group_id= $group_id;
    }
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        return [
             'group_id' => $this->group_id
        ];
    }
```

Comment: this  group_id will store in data column , I need it to store in group_id column

Comment: no, it will be stored in the group_id column in the table. edit your notification class with the changes I've told you and pass the group_id when you call your notification.

Comment: have a look at this article. it is addressing your issse https://medium.com/@alouinimedamin/customize-your-database-notification-and-database-channel-in-laravel-576c8fa5f498